# differentiation of the following equation 3

Tags: calculus, derivatives

i already done the differentiation, just wanna confirm either i got it right or wrong. Can someone verify this for me.

1) **f(x) = $ -3\over x^{5/2}$**

f '(x)

= $ 3({ 5\over 2}x^{3/2})$ . $\frac{1}{x^5}$

= $ { 15\over 2}x^{(3/2)-5}$

= ${ 15\over 2}x^{-7/2}$

**2) f(x) = $\frac{2x^2 + 3}{(x^3 - 4)^3}$**

f ' (x)

$= \frac{(4x) (x^3 - 4)^3  - (2x^2 + 3)[3(x^3 -4)^2 (3x)}{[(x^3 - 4)^3]^2}$

$= \frac{(4x) (x^3 - 4)^3  - 9x^2 (2x^2 + 3)(x^3 -4)^2}{(x^3 - 4)^6}$

$= \frac{(4x) (x^3 - 4)^3  - 9x^2 (2x^2 + 3)}{(x^3 - 4)^4}$  ---quotient rule

**3) f(x) = sin(x cos x)**

$f ' (x) = \cos [x \cos(x)] (\cos x - x \sin x)$

**4) f(x) = $x^2$ tan 2x**

$f ' (x) =  2x \tan (2x)$ + $2x^2$ $\sec^2 2x$

**5) f(x) = $ 3 \ln (\cos 3x) $**

$f ' (x) =  -9 \tan 3x$

Comment: Double check 1) and 2), and explain the intermediate steps.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i double check 1)and 2) already and include the intermediate steps for 1). Can you verify it for me?

Comment: Sorry, it's all right now.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i use quotient rule and include the intermediate step for 2)

Comment: Have you heard of [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)? It's really a huge help in verifying this kind of stuff.

Comment: @JoBe never heard of it. Will check it later. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1) $$\bigg( \frac{-3}{x^{5/2}} \bigg)'=-3x^\frac{-5}{2}=\frac{15}{2}
x^\frac{-7}{2}$$

2) $$ \bigg(\frac{2x^2+3}{(x^3-4)^3}\bigg)' =\bigg( (2x^2+3
)(x^3-4)^{-3}\bigg)' $$ $$= (4x)(x^3-4)^{-3} + (2x^2+3
)(-3)(x^3-4)^{-4}(3x^2) $$$$= (x^3-4)^{-3} [ 4x -9x^2(2x^2+3 )(x^3-4)^{-1}]
$$

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been through all of them, but I suggest you redo 1 and 2.

In 1, it should be $x^{-6}$, not $x^{-5}$

In 2, it should be $-9x^{2}(2x^{2}+3)$, not $-3(2x^{2}+3)$

Comment: I already got it for question 2. But for question 1, how did you come out with x^-6

Comment: It should be

$f'(x)=\frac{15}{2}x^{-7/2}$

which is the same as

$f'(x)=\frac{15}{2}x^{5/2}\frac{1}{x^{6}}$. I think you forgot to subtract one from the power when you differentiated.

Comment: i used quotient rule and for the denominator, v^2. So, didn't it suppose to be (5/2)x2= 5?

Comment: It's easier if you express $f(x)$ as $-3x^{-5/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(-\frac3{x^{5/2}})'=-3x^{-5/2}=-3(-\frac52)x^{-\frac52-1}=\frac{15}{2x^{7/2}}$$

$$\left(\frac{2x^2+3}{(x^3-4)^3}\right)'=\frac{(4x)(x^3-4)^3-(2x^2+3)\big(3(3x^2)(x^3-4)^2\big)}{((x^3-4)^3)^2}=\frac{4x(x^3-4)-9(2x^2+3)x^2}{(x^3-4)^4}=-x\frac{14x^3+27x+16}{(x^3-4)^4}$$